# What exactly is the equation for SVM classification for new example?

Tags: machine-learning, svm, predictive-models

I understand that in the case of Logistic Regression, we simply multiply our weights with Input example for classification. But what exactly is the equation that we calculate in the case of SVM to predict? I have already gone through Matlab's svmclassify, and it doesn't help. I will be absolutely grateful for a response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Burges's [A Tutorial on Support Vector Machines for Pattern Recognition](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/publication/a-tutorial-on-support-vector-machines-for-pattern-recognition/) provides you a very detailed introduction to SVMs. Just compare it to logistic regression, the decision function of SVMs for the binary classification case is

$$
f(\mathbf{x}) = \text{sgn} (\mathbf{w}^T \mathbf{x} + b)
$$

where $\mathbf{w} = \sum_i \alpha_i y_i \mathbf{x}_i$, $\alpha_i$ is zero for all cases, but the support vectors (those lying exactly at the separating hyperplane), and $y_i \in \{1, -1\}$ are the labels.

The reference gives in addition very clear and intuitive geometrical interpretations of these results. See that you it does not provide any score like logistic regression does. It does not model a (conditional) probability density. Please refere to the [scikit-learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html#scores-probabilities) documentation for a description of this issue, and ways to deal with it.

Comment: First link you mentioned is broken.

Comment: This answer would be improved if it reproduced the key content in the links.

Comment: I hope the answer is now sufficient